# Cannot find the declaration of element 'wsdl:definitions'

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I have tried to search a solution to my problem and didn't succeed.

When I am trying to validate my XML file with the XSD I am getting the next error:

> "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'wsdl:definitions'"

I am validating it with http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?

in other validator I am getting:

> element definitions: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

My XML/wsdl file is

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="IFBTCIBPSI" targetNamespace="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI">
  <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:QF2="urn:http://com.my.company/RSException_ARRAY" xmlns:QF1="urn:http://com.my.company/RSErrorMessage_ARRAY" xmlns:Q5="urn:com/EXCEPTION_ARRAY" xmlns:Q4="urn:com/IMOFDA" xmlns:Q3="urn:com/IMOC" xmlns:Q2="urn:com/IMIC" targetNamespace="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI">
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:http://com.my.company/RSErrorMessage_ARRAY" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=RSErrorMessage_ARRAY.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:http://com.my.company/RSException_ARRAY" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=RSException_ARRAY.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:com/IMIC" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=IMIC.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:com/IMOC" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=IMOC.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:com/IMOFDA" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=IMOFDA.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:com/EXCEPTION_ARRAY" schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI?xsd=EXCEPTION_ARRAY.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="IFBTCIBP">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Q2:IMIC" />
        <xsd:element ref="Q5:EXCEPTION_ARRAY" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="IFBTCIBPR">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Q3:IMOC" />
        <xsd:element ref="Q4:IMOFDA" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="RSError">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="QF1:RSErrorMessage_ARRAY" />
        <xsd:element ref="QF2:RSException_ARRAY" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IFBTCIBPR">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IFBTCIBPR" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RSError">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:RSError" name="fault">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IFBTCIBP">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IFBTCIBP" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IFBTCIBPSI">
    <wsdl:operation name="IFBTCIBP">
<wsdl:documentation />
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IFBTCIBP">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IFBTCIBPR">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:RSError" name="fault">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="IFBTCIBPSI" type="tns:IFBTCIBPSI">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="IFBTCIBP">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI/IFBTCIBP" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="fault">
        <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="IFBTCIBPSI">
<wsdl:documentation />
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:IFBTCIBPSI" name="IFBTCIBPSHttpS11Ep">
      <soap:address location="http://mycompany.com/IFBTCIBPSI" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

my xsd file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><xsd:schema 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:com/IMIC" 
targetNamespace="urn:com/IMIC">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="IMIC">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="ID" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="IT" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="CT" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="MI" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="KBC" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="TT" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="TI" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="CN" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="ST" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:date" />
<xsd:element name="IT" type="xsd:integer" />
<xsd:element name="CT" type="xsd:integer" />
<xsd:element name="MI" type="xsd:integer" />
<xsd:element name="KBC" type="xsd:integer" />
<xsd:element name="TT" type="xsd:integer" />
<xsd:element name="TI" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="CN" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="ST" type="xsd:integer" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Please your help.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

The XML document has its top-level elements in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/` (WSDL), so that it needs to be validated against the [XML Schema for WSDL](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/).

You will also need the "schema of schemas" (XML Schema for XML Schema) in scope, as an XML Schema is nested inside `wsdl:types`, to make sure that this part also gets validated properly.

The schema referenced in the question (for `urn:com/IMIC`) is relevant for the actual SOAP data (as it is imported by the nested schema), but not for the WSDL document, as far as I understand it. The apparent complexity comes from the two levels of validation:

- on the one hand SOAP data against WSDL (including against the nested XML Schema)
- on the other hand the WSDL document validated against the "meta-schema" (the topic of this question).

It is important to reason only on one level at a time.

In order to validate on [xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php) as well as most XML Schema validation engines, you need to supply the schema locations with an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute. This attribute takes a list of URLs: a schema namespace, its location (for WSDL it is the same as the namespace), another schema namespace, its location, etc. Since you need two schemas, this makes it four URLs, like so:

```
<wsdl:definitions
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  name="IFBTCIBPSI" 
  targetNamespace="http://com.my.company/IFBTCIBPSI"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
                      http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
                      http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
                      https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" >
    <!-- rest of document -->
</wsdl:definitions/>
```

Note that xmlvalidation.com seems to be missing two files (XMLSchema.dtd and datatypes.dtd) that it asks for. If it does, you can just copy and paste from these locations:

- https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd
- https://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd

On my side, the validation seems to then succeed (no errors found). Also oXygen does not complain.

Comment: Hi Ghislain, Thank for your answer, can you please tell/suggest me how can i solve that problem ? Thanks !!!

Comment: Hi Matan, yes, I have completed my answer with instructions specific to xmlvalidation.com (the xsi:schemaLocation is standardized however, so other engines should understand it as well). I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ghislain! 
First of all, I want to say thank you for your help. It's very appreciated! 
We checked your solution and it's passing validation on [xmlvalidation.com][1]
with usage of .dtd files provided. The problem, that the validation should pass over **xmllint** linux validator, without any additional external schema/files. 
Is it possible to edit/change/simplify the files from example to avoid usage of external .dtd files?
Thank you again!

  [1]: http://xmlvalidation.com

Comment: Hi Matan. I am happy to help. The two additional DTDs are in the external subset of XMLSchema.xsd. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with xmlvalidation.com or with xmllint, but assume that it needs these additional `.dtd` documents because it validates both against DTDs and XML Schemas. You should not need these DTDs if you deactivate DTD validation in your processor, but you will need the `.xsd` documents in any case, either fetched on the Web with the locations given in `xsi:schemaLocation`, or cached locally. Note that processors have some freedom in how this is done, but should document it.